# Cannot Understand the 555 IC Reset

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design, schematics, 555

I have designed the schematic diagram of the inner components of the 555 Timer IC for understanding the working of the IC, but not sure if I have designed it correctly or not. [image: 555 IC Schematic Diagram]
If it is correct can anyone please help me to understand how the **Reset** is working on the **RS flip-flop**.

**Modified**
[image: Modified Schematic Diagram of 555 IC]

Comment: where did you get this circuit from? It looks wrong.

Comment: Better to look at the actual circuit - http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/mtully/555%20folder/555%20timer.htm

Comment: Designed it by myself seeing the youtube video and other online tutorials. Can you please tell me where I made the mistake.

Comment: (*Grumpy oldman mode on*) - Is this the way people are learning stuff today? Youtube and online tutorials? What about books? How about looking at some datasheets of actual parts?

Comment: @EugeneSh. For your information, I am not an Electrical or Electronics student so don't have any books so Internet is the best place for me to learn.

Comment: Why are you attempting to design a 555, while there are tons of readily made chips and designs? Looks like you have based yours on one of these anyway.I agree you might not need a paper book to learn these days, but at least a soft copy of some comprehensive textbook is highly recommended if you are serious. Also you can find several pretty good free MOOCs on the subject.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am not designing to make a new 555 timer but for my own understanding. To get a clear picture how all the things work in the background.

Comment: Also worth looking at the truth table for an SR-Latch https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#SR_NOR_latch

Comment: So now with the **Modified Diagram**

If Vth > 2/3Vcc and Vtr > Vcc/3   (Vth is the Threshold Voltage and Vtr is the trigger voltage)
R = 1 and S = 0
Then Q = 0 and ~Q = 1
and Output at **Pin 3** will be 0
T1 will be active and discharge will happen at **Pin 7**

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct.

The reset pin is an active-low additional reset line of the flip flop, as shown before (and on the functional description on the 555 datasheet).

[image]

Your schematics must be modified. Here's my suggestions (in red).

Basically, the inverter creates an active high-reset. The OR gate allows to reset the flip flop either due to "threshold" voltage exceeded (CMP2 output high) or due to external reset (low) on pin 4. Basically it creates an additional reset input.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Diagram but this is already there in the Datasheet but RS Flip-Flop has two output Q and ~Q so want to design it that way. Can you please point out where is the mistake?

Comment: You need a flipflop with a reset. Or design a reset circuit around the flipflop. By any means the reset *input* cannot be connected to the FFs *outputs* as it is currently done.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok got it. There will be another **Reset Pin** along with **R Pin** right? But then what will be connected to **Q Pin**

Comment: Yes, don't get confused between the R, S and Set/Reset pins, even though R and S are actually originating from the same words.

Comment: @HimadriGanguly. Use an inverter on your external reset, to obtain an active high reset. Let's call it new_reset. Then put an OR gate: connect its, output to the R terminal of your reset, one of its input to the output of CMP2, and the other input to "new_reset". In a few minutes I will edit my answer to show this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is the **Output** inverted from the **RS flip-flop** before going out to **Pin3**?

Comment: In the circuit in this answer? Yes.

Comment: @next-hack modified the diagram accordingly can everyone please check if it is perfect now or still there is any error.

Comment: @next-hack But can you please explain why you are using an inverter to the external RESET input?

Comment: @HimadriGanguly Because in the original 555, the reset is active low. In your schematics (as well as in the "simplified schematics" I originally posted), the flip-flop reset ("R") is active-high.

Comment: Reset to Discharge still not right, it is direct invert to base

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, yes, in the original schematics it's true (But if you just connected the inverter directly to the discharge, then you would not reset the flip flop). At the end, functionally, (see the simplified schematics I've taken from Ti's datasheet) it is the same. When Reset is low, Qn will be high, and discharge BJT on. Another thing that the simplified schematic (as well as this) does not take into account is that reset overrides trigger which overrides threshold.

Answer (score 1):

RS is a dual NOR

Reset_ pulls down Discharge and resets RS FF.

[image]

You can also play with this simulator http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-555saw.html

One simplification of the Dual NOR GATE RS Flip looks like this.
[image]

But the OR gate shares common transistors so this is more minimalistic.
The latch function instead of crossover NOR gates uses a shared positive feedback R.
[image]